# Написать запрос к базе MySQL

Tags: sql

Есть три таблички: `books` с книгами, `authors` с авторами и `book_author`, где связи между ними по индексам. Отдельную табличку делал, потому что у книги может быть несколько авторов. Нужно написать один запрос на вывод таких столбцов "фамилия автора", "количество книг написанных без соавторов", "количество книг написанных в соавторстве".

Что должно получится в результате запроса с данными табличками:

```
"Автор"   "Без соавторов" "В соавторстве"
|Роулинг    | 2         | 0         |
|Кинг       | 1         | 2         |
|Поланик    | 1         | 0         |
|Толкин     | 1         | 0         |
|Штайнгёфель| 1         | 0         |
|Страуб     | 0         | 1         |
|О'Нэн      | 0         | 1         |
|Мерзляк    | 2         | 0         |
|Баряхтар   | 1         | 0         |
|Попель     | 1         | 0         |
```

Пробовал всячески это делать, но ничего не могу придумать. Буду благодарен хотя бы за совет по поводу логики запроса.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Время создания: Дек 23 2020 г., 10:27
-- Версия сервера: 10.3.22-MariaDB
-- Версия PHP: 7.1.33

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- База данных: ` library`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `authors`
--

CREATE TABLE `authors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(50) DEFAULT '''Не указано''',
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Не указано'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `authors`
--

INSERT INTO `authors` (`id`, `surname`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Роулинг', 'Джоан'),
(2, 'Кинг', 'Стивен'),
(3, 'Поланик', 'Чак'),
(4, 'Толкин', 'Джон Роналд'),
(5, 'Штайнгёфель', 'Андреас'),
(6, 'Страуб', 'Питер'),
(7, 'О\'Нэн', 'Стюарт'),
(8, 'Мерзляк', 'Иван'),
(9, 'Баряхтар', 'Сергей'),
(10, 'Попель', 'Светлана');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `books`
--

CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Без названия',
  `pages` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_publishing` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `date_receipt` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `books`
--

INSERT INTO `books` (`id`, `name`, `pages`, `id_publishing`, `year`, `amount`, `date_receipt`) VALUES
(1, 'Гарри Поттер и философский камень', 320, 2, 2002, 12, '2020-12-02'),
(2, 'Гарри Поттер и тайная комната', 380, 2, 2003, 8, '2020-09-16'),
(3, 'Бойцовский клуб', 420, 1, 2006, 5, '2019-10-10'),
(4, 'Середина мира', 432, 3, 2016, 1, '2017-01-29'),
(5, 'Сияние', 624, 1, 2008, 312, '2018-07-18'),
(6, 'Братство кольца', 566, 5, 2012, 26, '2019-12-06'),
(7, 'Талисман', 633, 1, 2006, 40, '2020-03-11'),
(8, 'Болельщик', 950, 1, 2015, 5, '2018-07-24'),
(9, 'Химия 7 класс', 240, 4, 2020, 30, '2020-08-20'),
(10, 'Физика 7 класс', 380, 4, 2018, 31, '2020-07-20'),
(11, 'Геометрия 7 класс', 530, 4, 2020, 28, '2020-05-22'),
(12, 'Алгебра 7 класс', 513, 4, 2019, 30, '2020-08-20');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `book_author`
--

CREATE TABLE `book_author` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_author` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_book` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `book_author`
--

INSERT INTO `book_author` (`id`, `id_author`, `id_book`) VALUES
(1, 2, 5),
(2, 2, 8),
(3, 2, 7),
(4, 6, 7),
(5, 5, 4),
(6, 1, 1),
(7, 4, 6),
(8, 1, 2),
(9, 3, 3),
(10, 7, 8),
(11, 8, 12),
(12, 8, 11),
(13, 10, 9),
(14, 9, 10);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `authors`
--
ALTER TABLE `authors`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `books`
--
ALTER TABLE `books`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `id_publishing` (`id_publishing`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `book_author`
--
ALTER TABLE `book_author`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `id_author` (`id_author`),
  ADD KEY `id_book` (`id_book`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `authors`
--
ALTER TABLE `authors`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=11;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `books`
--
ALTER TABLE `books`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `book_author`
--
ALTER TABLE `book_author`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `book_author`
--
ALTER TABLE `book_author`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `book_author_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_author`) REFERENCES `authors` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `book_author_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_book`) REFERENCES `books` (`id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Замените эти, несомненно, красивые, но абсолютно бесполезные, картинки, на текстовые форматированные CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, добавьте требуемый результат на показанных данных и точную версию SQL-сервера.

Comment: @Akina добавил дамп базы из PhpMyAdmin и пример желаемого вывода по данным из таблиц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t3.surname, 
       COUNT(t1.id_book) total,
       SUM(t2.id_book IS NULL) alone,
       COUNT(t1.id_book) - SUM(t2.id_book IS NULL) together
FROM book_author t1
LEFT JOIN book_author t2 ON t1.id_book = t2.id_book AND t1.id_author != t2.id_author
JOIN authors t3 ON t1.id_author = t3.id
GROUP BY t1.id_author
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=35e6a6ec3b75c1e12145ab139a126980)

Answer (score 1):

еще вариант с подзапросом, который считает число книг с единственным автором

```
SELECT a.id, a.surname
  , count(ba.id_book) AS total
  , count(x.id_book) AS single
  , count(ba.id_book) - count(x.id_book) AS coauthors
FROM authors AS a 
INNER JOIN book_author AS ba ON (ba.id_author = a.id)
LEFT JOIN (
         select id_book, min(id_author) as id_author
         from book_author
         group by id_book
         having count(id_author) = 1
     ) AS x ON (x.id_author = a.id AND x.id_book = ba.id_book)
GROUP BY  a.id, a.surname
```

[фиддл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/324759/11)